# how to add a separate delimiter for a specific field in data file - Perl

Tags: perl

I currently have a prep which takes a csv file, single line data, with multiple fields delimited by commas.  Then outputs a pipe delimited file.  The problem I have however, is that I now need to, for a certain field in the data, to be also delimited by a '-'

This is what I currently have

```
     $line = $_;
    $line =~ s/\,/\|/g;

    my @field = split(/\|-/, $line);
```

any help greatly appreciated. Sorry if i have been a bit vague with this also.

Comment: Posting sample data from your CSV file will be helpful.

Comment: `AC123,ABC ACC,666,123456789,987654321,MR J BLOGGS AND MRS H BLOGGS RE-DAVID BLOGGS,,,,01/03/2013`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to use multiple deliminators (note that it stores in `hash` not `array`); example 10 at  http://perlmeme.org/howtos/perlfunc/split_function.html

```
 my %values =  split(/[=;]/, $data);
```

So for your case, it will look something like

```
 my %field =  split(/[\|-]/, $line);
```

Else, you can always nest your splits and do something like following

```
my @field = split(/\|/, $line);
my @newField = split(/-/, $field[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Parsing a CSV is not as simple as you may think, so it's safer using a CPAN module to do this task, like [Parse::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/Parse-CSV-2.00/lib/Parse/CSV.pm). This module allows the configuration of the separator character. Example:

```
my $parser = Parse::CSV->new(
      file       => 'my_data.csv',
      sep_char   => ';'
);

while ( my $array_ref = $parser->fetch ) {
     # Do something...
}
```